# how to run java program on compute engine from windows 8

Tags: java, google-compute-engine

I am new with cloud computing...I'm totally in the dark that how to deploy a java program on compute engine to run there..

My program is about to take a series of 10,000  or more from user and sort it...

I know nothing about that where i would  place my java project in my pc or any command to deploy/run it on cloud.

I also read their getting started tutorial and some stuff for here
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cloud_computing
   but nothing found....

Sorry i know that this is very general question but i know someone would help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Compute Engine gives you nothing but a system with processor, ram and Hard Disk space with the installed OS you specify. You can access that system using an SSH online or gcloud tool provided by google. Now let's say you have installed Ubuntu or some other version of Linux on that machine, your question boils down to how do I run Java Program in Linux. Just Install the Java, create .java files, compile and Run them as you do in Linux Shell.

Comment: I have created an instance of windows server 2008 but it does not connect to  RDP.......... should i do some changes with firewall or anything else????